# How to delete from 2 tables that depend on each other in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with collection of objects, let's assume the table is called `items`. each item has some properties, and the id of the group into which it belongs.

```
items (id, name, created_at, group_id, ...)
```

For som reasons that I can't change, the item ids are first created and stored in a special table, and only then they are added to `items` table. So `items.id` has FK to `item_ids.id`.

```
item_ids (id, ..., ...)
```

Now I want to delete all the items of a given group. But if I delete them first from `items` table, I will lose their connection to the group and won't be able to delete them from `item_ids` table. Deleting `item_ids` first is also impossible, because doing so will violate the FK constraint and cause an error.

I don't want to use "in" because I'm afraid that there will be too many items to delete.

Is delete cascade my only option? Or is there another solution? How many ids can I safely put into an `in` clause?

Comment: See [Deferred constraints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-set-constraints.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the solution suggested by @Belayer, thank you!

First, change the FK constraint of the items table to be `deferrable`:

```
alter table items 
    ALTER CONSTRAINT item_id_fk DEFERRABLE INITIALLY immediate;
```

Then, in the transaction in which I delete the items, first set the constraint to be verified only at the end of the transaction (`deferred`), and then delete first the `item_ids` entries, and then the `items` entries:

```
begin;
set constraints item_id_fk deferred;
delete from item_ids using items where items.group_id in (...) and items.id = item_ids.id;
delete from items where group_id in (...);
commit;
```